# TreeMap strangley working

Tags: java, null, treemap

I have a HashMap matching a String with a double and I try to sort it by values using a TreeMap after some modifications on thoses values.

It works and I can print the whole tree, but when I try to access a specific value by it's key, it returns null about half of the time, always on the same keys, even though their values are not that different from the others.
Likewise, retrying to remove a key does not work.

Here is an example of my problem. It isn't really a part of my code, but it reproduces the same problem :

```
    Map<String, Double> freq = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    ValueComparator classif = new ValueComparator(freq);
    TreeMap<String, Double> sorted_freq = new TreeMap<String, Double>(classif);

    freq.put("bara" , 0.1142204454597373);
    freq.put("religieux" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("alliance" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("ethnique" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("officiers" , 0.1142204454597373);
    freq.put("ascendants" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("correspondait" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("toko" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("evenement" , 0.1142204454597373);
    freq.put("certainement" , 0.05711022272986865);
    freq.put("chance" , 0.05711022272986865);

    sorted_freq.putAll(freq);
    for(String key:freq.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key+" : "+freq.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(String key:sorted_freq.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key+" : "+sorted_freq.get(key));
    }
```

Here is the Comparator I am using to build the TreeMap :

```
 class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> freq) {
        this.base = freq;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) > base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        }else if(base.get(a)==base.get(b)){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } 
    }
}
```

If you have any insigth on that, please enlighten me.

Comment: What kind of modifications? If that comparator becomes inconsistent or incomplete, the TreeMap will stop working.

Comment: I tried the equals method and about half of the entries simply disappear ... The modifications are just to divide the values by an integer. The values I took in the example are the result of that modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that if two entries of your original map have the same value, then only the last inserted in `freq` will remain. Therefore the key that has been replaced in `freq` is removed from the treemap.

Example:

```
freq.put("bara" , 0.1142204454597373);
freq.put("religieux" , 0.05711022272986865);
freq.put("alliance" , 0.05711022272986865);
```

then `freq.get("religieux")` returns `null` because since it has the same value as `"alliance"` and `"alliance"` has been inserted afterwards, `"religieux"` has been replaced by `"alliance"` because they are considered equal by the comparator.

Also, as suggested in other answers, you need to compare the `Double` values doing `base.get(a).equals(base.get(b))`

Comment: +1 To solve that, you could compare the keys as well if the values are equal (change `return 0` to `return a.compareTo(b)`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solutions seems to correct my problem. I dont relly know anything about the use of the Comparator class, so it really helps

Comment: This may not fix the core issue of your compare method. Instead of using == you should be using equals in compare method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(base.get(a)==base.get(b))
```

This compares the instances of the Double-objects instead of the values. Try to change it to

```
if(base.get(a).doubleValue()==base.get(b).doubleValue())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your compare method as below.

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    if (base.get(a) > base.get(b)) {
        return -1;
    }else if(base.get(a).equals(base.get(b))){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    } 
}
```

this is the main reason for your code to fail

Comment: This just seems to make most of the entries disappear.

Comment: Your comparator implementation says to have only non duplicate values. that is the reason of entries having duplicate values missing as it returns 0 when adding entries from hashmap to treemap.

Comment: Alrigth. I just copied an implementation of the comparator. I know next to nothing about this class. Maybe I should learn a bit more about what I'm using :p